# urlrewrite.xml doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url-rewriting

I've been working on a Spring Project. I want my URL written in localhost:8080/app/main/something instead of localhost:8080/app/main.htm?type=something.
Or maybe something like localhost:8080/app/employee/input instead of localhost:8080/employee.htm?type=input, but so far the URL remains the same. Can somebody help me?

Here is my web.xml

```
        <filter>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>

                <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
                <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
            <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>



      <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>verse</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And here is my urlrewrite.xml

```
 <rule>
<from>^/main.htm?type=([a-z]+)$</from>
<to type="redirect">/main/something/</to>
 </rule>

 <rule>
<from>^/inputregion.htm$</from>
<to type="redirect">/main/region/input</to>
 </rule>
```

My viewResolver in servlet:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>                    
        </bean>
```

Comment: anyone? really need some help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out

```
<outbound-rule enabled="true">
        <from>^/main\.htm$</from>
        <to type="redirect">/dashboard/</to>

     </outbound-rule>



    <rule enabled="true">
        <from>/dashboard/</from>
        <to>/main.htm</to>
    </rule>
```